# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

when I try to run NPM RUN DEV in my Next Js project then my server is crashed and I got this error in my vs code:-

wait  - compiling /html/page (client and server)...

<--- Last few GCs --->

[4260:081272F0]   125513 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 617.9 (672.8) -> 614.7 (652.2) MB, 425.6 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.733, current mu = 0.602) last resort; GC in old space requested

[4260:081272F0]   125981 ms: Mark-Compact (reduce) 614.7 (652.2) -> 614.6 (651.7) MB, 467.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.554, current mu = 0.000) last resort; GC in old space requested

<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory.

Comment: Try getting more ram

Comment: `heap out of memory` sounds like it's trying to tell you that your heap ran out of memory. As ridiculous as it sounds, you'll need some more RAM.

Comment: i have i5 6th generation intel processor with 8gb ram and 500 gb SSD  . Is it not sufficient to run  nextjs project  ???

Comment: 8gb certainly should suffice, but is all of that available to nodejs?